# posting to a php website using C++ HTTPClient

Tags: c++, httpclient

Im learning C++ to program a micro-controller, it turns out that there aren't any libraries available yet for posting to facebook / twitter.

i have coding background in `PHP` and was able to implement posting to facebook timeline through the use of `API` with just a simple `HTML` with `Textarea` and a `button`.

was kinda wondering if its possible for C++ to post or push data into a website HTML and, with that website, i will be able to post status in my facebook / twitter.

i scanned through the available libraries of my micro-controller, and found out about `HTTPClient`   but not sure if this is the solution im looking for.

Comment: Which microcontroller? Which `HTTPClient` library?

Comment: im using 'mbed' as my micro-controller. it had "HTTPClient" what i wanted is to use the MCU to post into a website HTML page textarea and submits that data onto facebook or twitter.